# Installing R on Ubuntu Server - 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, r

I'm attempting to install the latest version of R (currently on v 3.0.2) on Ubuntu Server 14.04, and as suggested by [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431380/how-do-i-install-upgrade-r-base-to-the-latest-version) I've edited the /etc/apt/sources.list to include the following line:

```
 deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty universe
```

When I try to update the list of packages though, I get the following error

```
Err http://cran.rstudio.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://cran.rstudio.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I add a trailing forward slash to `trusty`, or remove `universe` in keeping with [this format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431380/how-do-i-install-upgrade-r-base-to-the-latest-version) as shown below:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

I get

```
E: Malformed line 49 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (absolute dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I thought maybe when `apt-get upgrade` accesses the sources.list it may be misformatting the url for the CRAN repository, because including `/dists/trusty/universe/` doesn't seem right to me, but I don't know if that is the actual issue, or what to do about it.

Comment: I don't understand. Where did you get the `http://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/` from? What makes you think that's an Ubuntu repository (doesn't look like one). That's not what my answer to the question you linked to was suggesting.

Comment: @terdon `http://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/` is one of the mirrors for CRAN in the UK. I also tried `http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu` and that didn't work either.

Comment: It should be `deb http://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/` I think. The trailing slash is important - see [List of sources can not be read Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/894427/178692)

Comment: @joeqesi yes, I know it's a CRAN mirror. You're treating it as an Ubuntu repository though, not a CRAN mirror! If it fails when using `http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu`, that's a very different situation, but that it fails with `mirrors.ebi.ac.uk` is normal since that's not a repository.

Comment: @terdon my mistake. However, I've just tried updating again with `http://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu` which did not work, and then tried updating with `http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu` which didn't work.

Comment: @steeldriver whenever I add the trailing slash to `trusty` I can't run `apt-get upgrade` as it considers the line to be malformed.

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question to reflect that. You may as well remove the `mirrors.ebi.ac.uk` stuff since it makes sense that that would fail. Just edit it and show us the line you added for the `cran.rstudio.com` and the error you got when trying to use it.

Comment: @terdon the http://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu mirror appears to work - at least for `xenial/` (don't have a trusty box I can test it on)

Comment: @steeldriver ah, yes, I hadn't checked the `/bin` subdir, I just saw that `  mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/` was a regular mirror site and not a repo.